# difficulty implementing login function using lucia-auth & mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js

i just started learning credential authentication and based on my research, a lot of people recommended lucia-auth for credential authentication. i am following every step in their documentation, but still getting errors in my code. i have attached a screenshot of the lines of code thats flagged as error

my schema
//model.ts

```
import { MongodbAdapter } from "@lucia-auth/adapter-mongodb";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
        {
            _id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            
                username: {
                    type: String
                }
            ,
            password: {
                type: String
            }
        } as const,
        { _id: false },
    )


const sessionSchema = new Schema(
        {
            _id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            user_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            expires_at: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            }
        } as const,
        { _id: false }
    )


    
    export const User = mongoose.models.User ?? mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
    
    export const Session =
      mongoose.models.Session ?? mongoose.model("Session", sessionSchema);
```

my login function //route.ts

```
import Link from "next/link";

import { Argon2id } from "oslo/password";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";


import { lucia } from "@/app/auth/lucia";
import { ActionResult } from "@/app/lib/form";
import { User } from "@/app/lib/models";



async function login(_: any, formData: FormData): Promise<ActionResult> {
    "use server";
    const username = formData.get("username");
    if (
        typeof username !== "string" ||
        username.length < 3 ||
        username.length > 31 ||
        !/^[a-z0-9_-]+$/.test(username)
    ) {
        return {
            error: "Invalid username"
        };
    }
    const password = formData.get("password");
    if (typeof password !== "string" || password.length < 6 || password.length > 255) {
        return {
            error: "Invalid password"
        };
    }

    const existingUser = User.find({username})
    if (!existingUser) {
        return {
            error: "Incorrect username or password"
        };
    }

    const validPassword = await new Argon2id().verify(existingUser.password, password);
    if (!validPassword) {
        return {
            error: "Incorrect username or password"
        };
    }

    const session = await lucia.createSession(existingUser.id, {});
    const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);
    cookies().set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
    return redirect("/");
}
```

initialization of lucia //lucia.ts

```
import { Lucia } from "lucia";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { cache } from "react";

import type { DatabaseUser, Session, User } from "lucia";
import { MongodbAdapter } from "@lucia-auth/adapter-mongodb";
import mongoose from "mongoose";


const adapter = new MongodbAdapter(
    mongoose.connection.collection("sessions"),
    mongoose.connection.collection("users")
);

export const lucia = new Lucia(adapter, {
    sessionCookie: {
        attributes: {
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        }
    },
    getUserAttributes: (attributes) => {
        return {
            username: attributes.username
        };
    }
});

export const validateRequest = cache(
    async (): Promise<{ user: User; session: Session } | { user: null; session: null }> => {
        const sessionId = cookies().get(lucia.sessionCookieName)?.value ?? null;
        if (!sessionId) {
            return {
                user: null,
                session: null
            };
        }

        const result = await lucia.validateSession(sessionId);
        // next.js throws when you attempt to set cookie when rendering page
        try {
            if (result.session && result.session.fresh) {
                const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(result.session.id);
                cookies().set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
            }
            if (!result.session) {
                const sessionCookie = lucia.createBlankSessionCookie();
                cookies().set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
            }
        } catch {}
        return result;
    }
);

declare module "lucia" {
    interface Register {
        Lucia: typeof lucia;
        DatabaseUserAttributes: {
            username: string
        };
    }
}
```

this is the screenshot of the error i am getting:

> Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Query<any[], any, {}, any,
> "find">'.
> [screenshot of lines of code with the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl0sH.png)
> Can someone help and possibly explain this to me so I can make sense of it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay, they have a discord server you can join. Paste the link to your question there hopefully you will see someone who has an idea of what is wrong with your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).